# Rewriting the Settings in Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, settings

I have set the name of my `Form text` in the `application settings` and I need to `rewrite` it. Is it possible as it is showing me that it is only a `readonly`.

I know that we can simply change it by using `me.text=""`
But I have a problem in my application as I have the below code where On every time the form loads it is erasing the text.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLayout(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs)

        MyBase.OnLayout(e)
        'Me.Text = CStr(Val(Me.Text) + 1)
        FillList()

        MyBase.OnLayout(e)
        If FontColor.Items.Count = 0 Then
            FontColor.Items.AddRange(Known_Color)
            FontColor.MaxDropDownItems = 20
        End If


        MyBase.OnLayout(e)
        If OutlineColor.Items.Count = 0 Then
            OutlineColor.Items.AddRange(Known_Color)
            OutlineColor.MaxDropDownItems = 20
        End If



        MyBase.OnLayout(e)
        If BorderColor.Items.Count = 0 Then
            BorderColor.Items.AddRange(Known_Color)
            BorderColor.MaxDropDownItems = 20
        End If


        MyBase.OnLayout(e)
        If BackgroundColor.Items.Count = 0 Then
            BackgroundColor.Items.AddRange(Known_Color)
            BackgroundColor.MaxDropDownItems = 20
        End If
    End Sub
```

Is there any workaround to do this?

Comment: Why are you calling MyBase.OnLayout(e) 5 times?

Comment: I am trying to paint the combo box with colour schemes and fonts something like border colour,font colour,background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about your Form Text in your application settings being readonly. Look at this [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx).

From above Link:

> There are two types of application settings, based on scope:
>
> - Application-scoped settings can be used for information such as a URL    for a Web service or a database connection string. These values
>     are    associated with the application. Therefore, users cannot change
>     them    at run time.
> - User-scoped settings can be used for information such as persisting    the last position of a form or a font preference. Users can change
>     these values at run time.
>
> You can change the type of a setting by using the Scope property.

In short if your application setting is application scoped you can not it change at runtime, you have to use a user scoped setting or roll your own storage.

Edit: to add to @Bojan 's answer. The [`OnLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlayout.aspx) event will be fired during the `InitializeComponent()` method and everytime you resize the form or change  the size of a control. I would personally move your initialization to the `Form_Load event` or to `New()`.

i.e.

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MyBase.OnLayout(e)
```

most probably this is where your mistake is.

You are setting the text and then you are calling the base class `OnLayout` event which is probably causing the text to get back to default value. If you want to change something do it after you call the case class event handler.

If you are just trying to change the text of the form why not just use `Form_Load` event handler without calling the base event handler.